# JSON tree to grid view

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, tree, grid

Good day! How to parse JSON tree structure using EXTjs to bring them to the table view? Below is the structure that I want to put it to grid, how to do it? How to set up the model and storage?

```
[
    {"WorckGroup":"3D",
     "Statistics":[
            {"Specialist":"V A K","SCallCount":64,"AverageDuration":0.1136067},
            {"Specialist":"K T A","SCallCount":170,"AverageDuration":0.1057270},
            {"Specialist":"L A V","SCallCount":71,"AverageDuration":0.4269940}]},

    {"WorckGroup":"GPSK",
     "Statistics":[
            {"Specialist":"B A V","SCallCount":60,"AverageDuration":0.1109374},
            {"Specialist":"K K A","SCallCount":17,"AverageDuration":0.1125816}]},

    {"WorckGroup":"RG",
     "Statistics":[
            {"Specialist":"K A F","SCallCount":128,"AverageDuration":0.0624402},
            {"Specialist":"O A V","SCallCount":115,"AverageDuration":0.3808017},
            {"Specialist":"F E U","SCallCount":74,"AverageDuration":0.2172953}]}
]


| 3D | V A K | 64  | 0.1136067 |
| 3D | K T A | 170 | 0.1057270 |
...
| RG | F E U | 74  | 0.2172953 |
```

Comment: Help, I need somebody
Help, not just anybody
Help, you know, I need someone

Answer (score 0):

That data structure looks to be good for a tree grid.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-grid

Otherwise you could process the response in an ajax request to loop through the data and use the loadData method in a store.